# Grok pattern (regex) to filter data from nested brackets

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, devops, logstash-grok, grok

I've tried to apply grok pattern to filter nested brackets in the logs which is as below,

```
[2022-05-20T02:21:54.715] [INFO] [{"id":"876g4jd8v36w0dhna2","data":"fetching public base-plans ..."}]
```

My grok pattern looks like this. But here, I'm unable to parse nested brackets (brackets inside brackets). Any help is much appreciated, since I'm trying this for long.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] \[%{WORD:logLevel}\] \[%{DATA:id}\]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working fine and will filter as expected (regex)

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] \[%{WORD:logLevel}\] \[\{\"id\":%{DATA:id},\"data\":%{DATA:response}\]"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be working fine.

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] \[%{WORD:logLevel}\] \[\{\"%{GREEDYDATA:id}\"\}\]
```

[image: grok pattern]